# Salida de datos PHP JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

Estoy tratando de recorrer una respuesta ajax con un for-in en jquery, pero la respuesta está compuesta por un array que contiene otros arrays.... No se si estoy haciendo mal la consulta con PDO para que me devuelva este resultado tan complejo... El caso es que no consigo entrar a los elementos del array, para así poder hacer un listado... Adjunto mi cídogo PHP, JS y la salida resultante

**PHP:**

```
/ EXECUTE QUERY MYSQL TYPE SELECT
public static function queryExecute($sql){
    $arrayData = array();

    try{

        $connection = DB::connect();

        $stmt = $connection->query($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->execute();

        // SAVE THE DATA IN ARRAY
        $arrayData = $stmt->fetchAll();


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
    }
return $arrayData;
}
```

**pagination.js**

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "listar/listar.php",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(respuesta){

    console.log(respuesta);

    // CREAMOS EL LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS EN INDEX
    for(var item of respuesta){
        for(var i of item){
            $(".movies").append(`
                <div>${i[0]}</div>
            `);
        }
    }

  },
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.');
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        console.log('Requested page not found [404]');
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');
      } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
        console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');
      } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
        console.log('Time out error.');
      } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
        console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
      } else {
        console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
  }
```

Salida:

Esta es la salida desde la consola del navegador, como se puede observar es un array que contiene otros arrays, pero como estoy recorriendo con un for-in no se hacerlo. He probado a recorrer el array respuesta con un for normal, pero no me muestra nada en consola...

```
    array(4) {
         [0]=>
      array(41) {
         ["id"]=>
          string(6) "366921"
         ["id_categoria"]=>
          string(1) "0"
         ["categoria"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["ruta_categoria"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["id_subcategoria"]=>
          string(1) "0"
         ["subcategoria"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["marca"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["id_marca"]=>
          string(1) "0"
         ["id_proveedor"]=>
          string(1) "0"
         ["tipo"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["ruta"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["estado"]=>
          string(1) "0"
         ["url_producto"]=>
          string(0) ""
         ["titulo"]=>
          string(49) "SOPORTE APPROX APPSTSANITIZER02 PARA DISPENSADOR"
       ["titular"]=>
         string(0) ""
       ["descripcion"]=>
       string(0) ""
        ["youtube"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["multimedia"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(16) "APPSTSANITIZER02"
    ["proveedor"]=>
    string(5) "MYLAR"
    ["ean"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["costo"]=>
    string(4) "75.9"
    ["canon"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["detalles"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["precio"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["portada"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["vistas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vistasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorSubCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["oferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["precioOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["descuentoOferta"]=>
     string(1) "0"
    ["imgOferta"]=>
     string(0) ""
    ["finOferta"]=>
     string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["peso"]=>
     string(1) "0"
    ["entrega"]=>
     string(1) "0"
    ["fecha"]=>
     string(19) "2020-09-16 07:14:29"
  }
  [1]=>
     array(41) {
       ["id"]=>
        string(6) "366920"
       ["id_categoria"]=>
        string(1) "0"
       ["categoria"]=>
        string(0) ""
       ["ruta_categoria"]=>
        string(0) ""
       ["id_subcategoria"]=>
        string(1) "0"
       ["subcategoria"]=>
        string(0) ""
       ["marca"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["id_marca"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["id_proveedor"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ruta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["estado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_producto"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["titulo"]=>
    string(49) "SOPORTE APPROX APPSTSANITIZER02 PARA DISPENSADOR"
    ["titular"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["youtube"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["multimedia"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(16) "APPSTSANITIZER02"
    ["proveedor"]=>
    string(5) "MYLAR"
    ["ean"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["costo"]=>
    string(4) "75.9"
    ["canon"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["detalles"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["precio"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["portada"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["vistas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vistasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorSubCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["oferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["precioOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["descuentoOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["imgOferta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["finOferta"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["entrega"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-16 07:14:29"
  }
  [2]=>
     array(41) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "366919"
    ["id_categoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["categoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ruta_categoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["id_subcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["subcategoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["marca"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["id_marca"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["id_proveedor"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ruta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["estado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_producto"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["titulo"]=>
    string(59) "SOPORTE APPROX APPSTSANITIZER01 PARA DISPENSADOR AJUSTABLE
"
    ["titular"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["youtube"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["multimedia"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(16) "APPSTSANITIZER01"
    ["proveedor"]=>
    string(5) "MYLAR"
    ["ean"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["costo"]=>
    string(4) "49.9"
    ["canon"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["detalles"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["precio"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["portada"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["vistas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vistasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorSubCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["oferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["precioOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["descuentoOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["imgOferta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["finOferta"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["entrega"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-16 07:14:29"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(41) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "366918"
    ["id_categoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["categoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ruta_categoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["id_subcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["subcategoria"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["marca"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["id_marca"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["id_proveedor"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ruta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["estado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_producto"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["titulo"]=>
    string(59) "SOPORTE APPROX APPSTSANITIZER01 PARA DISPENSADOR AJUSTABLE
"
    ["titular"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["youtube"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["multimedia"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(16) "APPSTSANITIZER01"
    ["proveedor"]=>
    string(5) "MYLAR"
    ["ean"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["costo"]=>
    string(4) "49.9"
    ["canon"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["detalles"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["precio"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["portada"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["vistas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventas"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vistasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ventasGratis"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ofertadoPorSubCategoria"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["oferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["precioOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["descuentoOferta"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["imgOferta"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["finOferta"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["entrega"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-16 07:14:29"
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. Por la forma como tratas la respuesta en succes parece que esperaras que los items vinieran formateados y listos para ser agregados dentro de un elemento de clase .movies. Eso puede hacerse preparándolos luego de ejecutar la consulta y antes de devolverla. Por favor indica en la pregunta cómo quieres presentarlos y qué campos deben ser incluidos.

Comment: ¿Cómo realizas la salida del arreglo desde PHP, con `var_dump()`? Al menos así parece y debería ser con `json_encode()`; en tu petición AJAX agregas `dataType: 'json'` y podrías acceder a los datos para manipular más fácilmente.

Comment: Gracias a ambos. Opté por formatear la salida desde PHP. Gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he resulto, recorrí el array con PHP e hice la salida desde PHP

De esta manera, quizás no es lo más correcto, pero al no ser MVC hay que adaptarse

```
$resultado = DB::queryExecute("SELECT DISTINCT titulo, codigo, proveedor, costo, stock, portada FROM comparador ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");


for($i=0; $i<count($resultado); $i++){
    echo 
        "<div class='col-md-3'>".
            "<img src=".$resultado[$i]['portada'].">".
            "<h5>".$resultado[$i]["titulo"]."</h5>"."\n".
            "<span> Proveedor: ".$resultado[$i]["proveedor"]."</span>\r\n".
            "<span> PN:".$resultado[$i]["codigo"]."</span>\r\n".
            "<span class='portes'>";
                        if($resultado[$i]["proveedor"] === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 5.90€ +IVA<p>
                                  <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 200€ +IVA</p>";
                        }

                        else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 3.90€ +IVA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 3€ +IVA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 10.90€ +IVA</p>
                                 <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 300€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 5€ +IVA</p>
                                  <p>PORTES GRATIS 200€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>
                                  <p>MENOS DE 60€ GASTOS DE MANIPULACION 2.5€ +IVA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 3€ +IVA</p>
                                 <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 200€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 5€ +IVA</p>
                                 <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 500€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 4€ +IVA</p>
                                 <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 200€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                            echo "<p>PORTES 11€ +IVA</p>
                                 <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 200€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        } else if ($proveedor === "PROVEEDOR") {
                             echo "<p>PORTES 6€ +IVA</p>
                                  <p>GRATIS A PARTIR DE 400€+IVA, EL CANON NO CONTABILIZA</p>";

                        }
            echo "</span>";
            echo "<div>".
                    "<span>Stock: </span>"."<span class='label label-danger stock'>".$resultado[$i]["stock"]."</span>".
                  "</div>";
            echo "<div class='text-danger precio'>".
                    "<span> Precio: ".$resultado[$i]["costo"]."€"."</span>".
                 "</div>";
            echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'>
                        <a href='controladores/generarOferta.php?'".$resultado[$i]['titulo'].">
                            <button class='btn btn-success'>Crear Oferta</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>".
        "</div>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a los arrays desde la respuesta que te da el PHP para limpiar la salida ejemplo:

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
        foreach ($data as $subare) {
            echo json_encode($subare);
        }
    }
```

los **foreach** variaran en función de como de multidimensional sea tu array